# Number of meetings needed for everyone to know everyone

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, average

There are 100 people on an island. Each person has an unlimited number of name-tags with his name on it. (Everyone has a different name)

When two people meet, each gives the other an unlimited number of all the name-tags that they currently have. (E.g. If person A meets person B they will both end up with having name-tags A and B with them. If person B then meets person C then persons B and C will both have all the name-tags A, B, and C while person A still only has name-tags A and B) [The name-tags never run out]

How many meetings between two people will it usually take until everyone has everyone's name-tag? Note: A person X has the name-tag of person Y if and only if there exist persons $A_1, A_2, ..., A_r$ such that $Y\rightarrow A_1\rightarrow A_2\rightarrow ... \rightarrow A_r \rightarrow X$ where $M\rightarrow N$ means M meets N and the meetings occured in exactly this order (from left to right).

Comment: Sounds like the discrete version of Poisson.  What setups have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried much to be honest. I made this question up by myself and it seems interesting.

Comment: It's like each person writes down a list of people they have previously met, and when any two people meet they add to their list people who the other person has met. I'm just wondering how long it takes for everyone to be on everyone's list.

Comment: This is known as the Gossip problem (or telephone problem).  links to some standard papers on it can be found online, eg here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576326/minimal-time-gossip-problem

Comment: Sounds like you might benefit by looking at directed graphs and asking how many edges are involved in forming a sort-of "complete" digraph.