# Network Connectivity Problem

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Assume a network (a complete undirected graph) comprised of $N$ participants (vertices). Each person holds a different piece of information, unknown to all other members. The participants can communicate in pairs, and with each communication, the two parties learn all the information that the other one knows. What is the least amount of such one-to-one exchanges, needed so that every participant knows everybody's information?

Some ideas that are not optimal:
The simplest solution is having everyone talk to everyone else (i.e. $N(N-1)$ communications).
A better idea is to have one participant collect everyone's information ($N - 1$ exchanges), and then redistribute it ($N - 2$ since the last one has already received everyone's information) for a total of $2N - 3$ exchanges.

Hint: Prove that the answer for $N = 5$ is $6$.

EDIT: The solution can be found in this MSE question: [Minimal time gossip problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576326/minimal-time-gossip-problem)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2959806/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: @mrtaurho Thanks for replying. I tried to improve my question. Please have a look and see if it is acceptable now.

Comment: It is a way better like this. Nevertheless to make it perfect - and for further usage within questions and answers here on MSE - use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts properly :)

Comment: Nice question! I found an algorithm which requires 6 exchanges for 5 participants. But I can't prove it can't be improved and still has no clue for general case :(

Comment: @lesnik It turns out this is a well-known problem. The solution consists of two parts: Prove that $2N - 4$ is enough for every $N>4$, then prove it can't be done in less. The first is easy: one of four “chief” gossips first calls each of the remaining $N−4$ gossips, then the four learn each other’s (hence everyone’s) information in 4 calls (the optimal number for $N=4$ is 4), and finally one of the four chiefs calls each of the other $N−4$ gossips (verbatim from Baker's proof, in the link above). For the second part, use reductio ad absurdum, assuming there is a solution $≤ 2N-5$.